# IP restrict Azure VM role

Tags: security, ftp, azure

We're currently deploying a VM role to Azure; which hosts a site running under IIS 7.5 and an FTP server. One of our requirements is that the site and FTP be IP restricted to ours and our partners. I know I can do this in IIS for the web server; but is there anyway to IP restrict the FTP endpoint? I know I can just password protect both; but I want to see what my options are. Any constructive input is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please follow this post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742665/linux-virtual-machine-at-azure-how-to-apply-ip-restriction/20744613?noredirect=1#comment31116083_20744613

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to configure the Windows Firewall, either when you create the image, or by using the Firewall GUI if the firewall rules are not in your image. You can automate setting these rules in a script through the Windows Firewall API.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the same as outside of Azure.  So the Windows Firewall will work well.  Anything you are using currently to do it you should be able to do in Azure as well.