# Linux Virtual Machine at Azure - how to apply IP restriction

Tags: linux, security, unix, azure

I have LINUX VM on Windows Azure (Ubuntu), i have a web application running there and client Socket application.  I want to restrict the ACCESS to limited IP's who can access the application via http and via TCP.

Please advice what is easiest and reliable way to restrict the IP access to Ubuntu Linux VM at Windows Azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

- Set up iptables or something similar within the VM itself
- St up endpoint Access Control Lists (ACL's) on your input endpoints. You can do this either through PowerShell or through the portal.

With ACL, you'll have an ordered list of allow-range and deny-range, specified in CIDR format. You can then allow/block ranges of IP addresses, such as your own data center's IP or even another Azure service's IP address.

From the portal, you'll see a **MANAGE ACL** option on the bottom of the Endpoint page of your VM:

[image]

Now you can enter IP ranges to allow and deny, and you can reorder them with the arrows on the right.
[image]

Comment: Many thanks, ACL is amazing. I want to deny everyone and want to permit only couple of IP address.   Any way to block everyone except IP to permit?

Comment: Try adding rules just for the IP ranges you want to permit. All others should be blocked.